# Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I was messing around with inheritance in C++ and wanted to know if anyone had any insight on the way it functions. Code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class AA {
 int aa;
 public:
 AA() {cout<<"AA born"<<endl;}
~AA(){cout<<"AA killed"<<endl;} 
virtual void print(){ cout<<"I am AA"<<endl;}
};

class BB : public AA{
 int bb;
 public:
 BB() {cout<<"BB born"<<endl;}
~BB() {cout<<"BB killed"<<endl;}
 void print() {cout<<"I am BB"<<endl;}
};

class CC: public BB{
 int cc;
 public:
 CC() {cout<<"CC born"<<endl;}
~CC(){cout<<"CC killed"<<endl;}
 void print() {cout<<"I am CC"<<endl;}
};


int main()
{
 AA a;
 BB b;
 CC c;
 a.print();
 b.print();
 c.print();     
 return 0;
}
```

so I understand that when you inherit something you inherit constructors and destructors. So when I do , "BB b" it prints "AA born". So the question I have

1. Is an instance of AA created
2. If yes, what is it called and how can I reference it?
3. If no, why is the constructor being called

Comment: "Is an instance of A created" - I assume you mean `AA`?

Comment: so a followup question, if AA had a private member/function, would b.AA::privatefunction() be valid??

Comment: No, it wouldn't be. Outside of a class only friends can touch `private` parts. If it was `protected` then it would be valid within `BB`, but not from within `main`.

Comment: @awoodland upvote for "only friends can touch private parts"

Comment: @Mranz - that's one of my favorite C++ phrases. Nobody *ever* forgets `private` and `friend` after that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inheritance implements the "IS-A" relationship. Every `BB` is therefore also an `AA`.

You can see this in a number of ways, the easiest to demonstrate is:

```
BB b;
AA *aptr = &b;
```

Here your `BB` instance `b` is being pointed at by a pointer which only thinks of itself as pointing to an `AA`. If `BB` didn't inherit from `AA` then that wouldn't be legal.

The interesting thing is that when you call:

```
aptr->print();
```

It still prints "I am BB", despite the fact that the pointer you used is of type `AA *`. This happens because the `print()` method is `virtual` (i.e. polymorphic) and you're using a pointer. (The same would also happen with a reference too, but the type must be one of those for this behaviour to happen)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is an instance of A created

Sort of.  The `BB b;` code will allocate a `BB` instance.  Part of that object is an `AA`.

> 1. If yes, what is it called and how can I reference it?

Assuming the `BB b;` variable declaration, your part-of-`BB` `AA` instance is called `b`.  If you want to call specific methods in `AA` that are hidden by `BB` methods, such as `.print()`, you need to invoke them like so:

```
BB b;
b.AA::print();
```

Comment: so a followup question, if AA had a private member/function, would b.AA::privatefunction() be valid??

Comment: you cannot call object private function, only this object can do this

Comment: @noob: that syntax is valid for private functions anywhere the private call is allowed (e.g. inside member functions).  Note that inside a member function, you can invoke it as `this->AA::privatefunction()`, or simply `AA::privatefunction()`.

Answer (score 2):

`BB` **is** an instance of `AA`. You don't need to access anything special, because you already have that type.

When `BB` inherits from `AA`, here's how it's constructed.

1. Call `AA` constructor
2. Initialize member fields
3. Call `BB` constructor

When destruction happens, this happens in reverse.

1. Call `BB` destructor
2. Destroy member fields (specific to `BB`)
3. Call `AA` destructor

Oh, and you have at least one virtual function inside of `AA`. That means you need to make `AA`'s destructor virtual (or bad things will happen).

Comment: The destructor only needs to be `virtual` if it's going to be deleted virtually. In this case it doesn't matter at all, the behaviour is well defined. (I.e. it's only bad if you use `new`+`delete` *and* you call `delete` on a pointer to a base rather than the most derived).

Comment: @awoodland: how can you guarantee that this object won't be deleted virtually? so this recommendation is good, this should be default implementation even in such simple examples

Comment: You can't be sure it won't, but the current wording implies that the behaviour of this code as it stands is undefined, which it isn't. It's a rule of thumb, not a requirement, which is not clear from the wording.

Answer (score 1):

In object-oriented languages, there are two main ways of creating objects that inherit from another one: concatenation and delegation. The first one is the most popular, the second is used in prototype-based languages.

Concatenation means that when B inherits from A, there are two parts in the object: in the first part of the object (of length equal to the size of A), the attributes (member variables/fields in C++) of A live. In the other part, there lives whatever attributes B adds to the object. Constructors for each involved class (A and B) are executed so all parts (all attributes) are initialized correctly.

Though the object is managed as a single unit, you can point it with a pointer of class A. In that case, the pointer only lets you *see* the first part, the part pertaining to class A (i.e. its attributes), but not the attributes from B, since the pointer can only *see* from the beginning to beginning + size of class A.

Say class A contains an integer x:

```
class A {
public: int x;
};
```

and B contains an integer y:

```
class B: public A {
public: int y;
} obB;
```

This means that an object of class B will have a length of 8 bytes (for 32 bits), the length of x plus the length of y, while the length of A is of only 4 bytes, the length of x. A pointer of class A to `objB`:

```
A * ptrA = &objB;
```

will only *see* `x`,

```
cout << ptrA->x << endl;
cout << ptrA->y << endl; // ERROR
```

while a pointer to B:

```
B * ptrB = &objB;
```

will be able to access both, x and y:

```
cout << ptrB->x << ',' << ptrB->y << endl;
```

In order to completely understand this, you need to know that `ptrB->y` is roughly translated into `*( ( (int *) ptrB ) + 1 )`, but that's another story.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A class that derives from a base class contains that base class as a *subclass*, so an instance of the derived class contains a base *subobject*.

The subobject is constructed first. The constructor that is used for that is yours to determine: If you don't say anything, the default constructor is used; otherwise, the constructor that you specify in the base initializer list is called. Example:

```
struct Base
{
  Base() { }             // default constructor
  Base(int, double) { }  // some other constructor
  char q; 
};

struct A : Base
{
};

struct B : Base
{
  B() : A(12, 1.5) { }
};
```

Both `A` and `B` contain `Base` as a subclass. When you say `A a;`, the subobject's default constructor is called. When you say `B b`, the subobjects other constructor is called, because you said so.

As a consequence, if the base class has no accessible default constructor, then you must specify an accessible constructor explicitly.

You can reference members of the subobject by qualifying the name: `a.Base::q` or `b.Base::q`. If the name is unambiguous, that's the same as just `a.q` and `b.q`. However, when you deal with overridden or hidden member functions (and maybe multiple virtual inheritance), being able to specify the subobject explicitly may be useful or even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little easier to understand when I give the structs more meaningful names:

```
class Animal;
class Dog : public Animal;
class Beagle : public Dog;
```

[When I create a `Dog b`...]

- Is an instance of `Animal` created?

  Yes, creating a `Dog` also creates an `Animal`, because the `Dog` *is* an `Animal`.
- If yes, what is it called and how can I reference it?

  The `Dog b` is the `Animal` instance. If you wanted to explicitly call the `Animal`
  versions of the method, you could use `b.Animal::print()` to tell the compiler
  to explicitly call the `Animal` version of the function.
- If no, why is the constructor being called?

  The `Dog b` *is* an an `Animal`, so constructing a `Dog` also constructs itself as an `Animal`.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/522371508982b56f

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance in c++ means the ability of objects in one class to inherit properties of another class which implements the reusablity concept. This means that it is not necessary to create a new methods and just override the existing one, if required. Saves a lot of work.