# Relation between base class constructor arguements with derived class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I cannot understand this statement:**"If the base class has constructor with arguments,then it is mandatory for derived class to have constructor and pass arguments to base class constructor."**
Please use some program if you can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506086/inheritance-in-c)

Comment: Is the meaning of any of the terms unclear (base class, constructor, constructor with arguments, mandatory, derived class, pass arguments)? What do you think will happen if a base class has argument-requiring constructor and does not get any?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a base class called Animal and a derived class named Dog. You will want to call Animal's constructor inside of Dog's constructor to initialize the inherited member variables. A very basic example looks like this:

```
class Animal
{
int num_legs;
public:
Animal(int legs): num_legs(legs){}
};

class Dog: public Animal
{
public:
// now we send the number of legs to the Base class
Dog(int legs): Animal(legs) {}
};
```

If you rely on the default constructor of Dog, you will end up with an uninitialized variable for legs in this case.

Comment: I would have `Dog(): Animal(4) {}`

Comment: It might help to explain why relying on the standard constructor (the one without arguments) does not help. It seems obvious, but obviously not to the asker. I.e try to compile `Dog(int legs): Animal() {}`, show the error and explain it.